# Loop terminates prematurely in R - replacement has length zero

Tags: r, overlapping-features, sf, replace

I managed to create a **for** loop in R with my rudimentary skills, and it works to an extent. I get the error "replacement has length zero", **which I've seen in other questions but for loops that do not run at all**.

Here's my specific situation explained so the code is easier to understand (working with sf objects) : I have a polygon representing my study area. I create random points inside of it, around each of them I create a buffer. Then I extract the part of these buffers that overlaps with a particular feature, and calculate the area of this intersection. I want to repeat the whole process 100 times.

This works perfectly by itself, but when I try to run a loop, it terminates after giving me some values (sometimes I get 60 values, sometimes 9, it's pretty random).
Here's the code:

```
list_of_shared_areas <- rep(NA,100)   #*creating an object to store the results*

for (i in 1:100) {
  randos<-st_sample(x=study_area, size=10,type="random") 
  #*creating 10 random points inside my study area*
  buf_rand<- st_buffer(randos, dist = 200) 
  #*creating a buffer of radius=200 around each random point*
  shared<-st_intersection(feature, buf_rand) 
  #*extracting the part of those buffers that overlaps with the feature of interest*
  area_shared<- st_area(shared) 
  #*calculating the area of overlap*
  list_of_shared_areas[i]<-area_shared
  #*replacing the NA values in the object I created before the loop*  
  }
```

Like I mentioned, the loop does run, but stops after giving me some values. My guess is that sometimes the polygons created from the random points do not overlap with my feature, therefore the intersection is =0, which means the area cannot be calculated.

If that interpretation is correct, how do I solve it to get a "0" value in those cases, and keep the loop running?

Comment: If two non-overlapping features are `st_intersection`-ed, the result is an empty geometry and that has an area of 0 which should get put into your list element without error. Use the `traceback()` function after an error to see where exactly the error happened, or set the random seed with `set.seed(1)` to get reproducible code - change the seed value until you get an error then attack the problem with the debug function.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Spacedman. The traceback() function returns "No traceback available". Setting the random seed with set.seed(1) allowed me to retrieve more values from my loop (97 instead of the 100 I want, then I get the same error as before, "replacement has length zero"). So I'm still puzzled about what's causing the problem.

Comment: Now you have a reproducible example (ie it should always crash out at 97 with that seed) you can try printing out things like the computed area or some of the other partial computations to see where its crashing, eg `message("area_shared is ", area_shared)` after computing it but before assigning it into the results. Throw lots of `message` functions around to see what lines are running.

Comment: If you are running this interactively then when it crashes you should have the current values of all the variables to inspect. Any of them not what you expect?

Comment: As per [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 2):

The result from `st_area` depends on what kind of object you feed it. Let's make some objects. First, three simple `sfg` polygons - the first two overlap, the third one doesn't:

```
b0 = st_buffer(st_point(c(0,0)),.1)
b1 = st_buffer(st_point(c(0,0.05)),.1)
b2 = st_buffer(st_point(c(.5,.5)),.1)
```

`st_area` of intersecting or non-intersecting objects here is well defined, and zero for non-overlapping:

```
st_area(st_intersection(b0,b1))
[1] 0.02150909
st_area(st_intersection(b0,b2))
[1] 0
```

but as soon as you wrap them into `sfc` objects (as needed to make geometry vectors for sf data frames, for example), this doesn't hold true:

```
st_area(st_intersection(st_sfc(b0),st_sfc(b1)))
[1] 0.02150909
st_area(st_intersection(st_sfc(b0),st_sfc(b2)))
numeric(0)
```

Giving a `numeric(0)` result which you can't put into a vector without getting the error you get from your question code. This is because the resulting intersection has 0 features:

```
st_intersection(st_sfc(b0),st_sfc(b2))
Geometry set for 0 features 
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
CRS:           NA
```

and I guess its logical that if the `st_area` of a thing with N elements is a vector of length N with an area for each element, then the length here should be zero.

A simple fix is to merge the intersected feature vector into a geometry collection, and take the area of that, which works in all cases:

```
st_area(st_geometrycollection(st_intersection(st_sfc(b0),st_sfc(b2))))
[1] 0
st_area(st_geometrycollection(st_intersection(st_sfc(b0),st_sfc(b1))))
[1] 0.02150909
```

The other approach is to test for the length of the vector and use zero for the area if the length is zero, as in another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

@Spacedman's comment mentions that the area of non-overlapping objects will be 0, but it does not appear to be the case. As far as I experienced, the intersection of two non-overlapping objects is an SF object/geodataframe of dimension `0 * n` (0 being the rows and n the columns) and has no geometry (rather than an empty geometry). Its `st_area` will be empty (`length(st_area(x))` will output `0`), so this is what might trigger the error message you see.

To check, you can print the result of your `st_area` operation.

I'm not sure this is a very elegant solution, but if this is indeed the cause problem, you could try this:

```
list_of_shared_areas <- rep(NA,100)   #*creating an object to store the results*

for (i in 1:100) {
  randos <- st_sample(x=study_area, size=10,type="random") 
  buf_rand <- st_buffer(randos, dist = 200) 
  shared <- st_intersection(feature, buf_rand) 

  if (dim(shared)[1] > 0) { # checks that the intersection SF object has at least one row, i.e. that your objects intersect
    list_of_shared_areas[[i]] <- st_area(shared)
  } else {
    list_of_shared_areas[[i]] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also move the check earlier in your loop by using `st_intersects()`, which returns a boolean. If true, your two objects intersect: compute the area of intersection and add it to the list. Else, return 0.

Comment: Both suggestions worked.